# want to remove show/hide link from this code

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

Using the following code for facebook comment box on my site. There is a link to **show or hide** Comments box. I just want to remove this link and make the comment box appear always.

Code in **header.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link').toggle(
        function () {
            if($('#box').text() == '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'./comments.php?url=<?php echo $domain.$path; ?>',
                    method:'GET',
                    success:function(r) {
                        $('.link').html('hide comments &and;');
                        $('#box').html(r).hide().slidedown(1000);
                    },
                    error:function() {
                        alert('file does not exist');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $(this).html('Hide Comments &and;');
                $('#box').slideDown(750);
            }
        },
        function () {
            $(this).html('Show Comments &or;');
            $('#box').slideUp(750);
        }
    );
});
```

Code in **index.php**

```
<span class="link" style="color:#FFA300;cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;">Show Comments (<fb:comments-count href=<?php echo $domain.$path; ?>></fb:comments-count>) &or;</span>
```

Code in **comments.php**

```
     <?php
if(isset($_GET['url']))
{
?>
<div style="padding:5px;">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments href="<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>" num_posts="5" width="626"></fb:comments>
<script>FB.XFBML.parse();</script>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

I have little knowledge in PHP and other languages and due to that i am unable to figure out the necessary changes required to make this comment box appear without clicking show comments link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  $(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:'./comments.php?url=<?php echo $domain.$path; ?>',
       method:'GET',
       success:function(r) {
         $('#box').html(r).slidedown(1000);
       },
       error:function() {
         alert('file does not exist');
       }
    });
  });
```

Comment: should i replace whole code in header.php with this one?

Comment: Replace the code you displayed in this question. If that is all the code, then yes. I have obviously not tested this. I am on my phone so I can't test it even if I wanted to. Look in the console for typos

Comment: Nice indentation and there does not look to be typos, I have to ask. I assume you're using a programming keyboard? Which one. Can't seem to find a decent one!

Comment: Actually here I just deleted code and clicked the {} button on some selected areas. When I'm on my iPad I use a Logitech BT one with all the {}[]() in the right places :)

Comment: @mplungjan i replaced the header.php code with your code and it worked. Only thing i noticed is that **comment** on the last uploaded picture changes on home page **(.com)** , **.com/index.html ( when home button is clicked after navigating a few pic)** and when linked to that same pic is visited **(.com/abc.jpg)**.  I believe same is the case with the previous code and it must be related to some URL code.

Comment: Yes: $domain.$path;

Comment: Sure. Change `<?php echo $domain.$path; ?>` to whatever you need it to be - something I cannot guess from your comments. Perhaps a new question?

Comment: @mplungjan Site is based on Php coding, so i cannot change it to specific URL

Comment: @mplungjan I have been searching for a solution to resolve this issue but couldnt find anything. I have managed to figure out the url to use with comment plugin which is canonical Url of the image <?php echo $domain.dirname($path); ?><?php echo $cur_image['filename'].".html"; ?> but when i insert this in data-href of comment plugin, the plugin gives url error. Can u help me with this, just need to use this php url code within the comment plugin but i dont know how.

Comment: @mplungjan fyi i have used the same php url code with fb share button data-href and it works perfectly, But giving URL error when used in FB comments plugin

Comment: @DarylGill Can u help

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code AND how it rendered the HTML instead of posting in comments

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks but i get this to work, changed `<?php echo $domain.$path; ?>` to `<?php echo $domain.dirname($path); ?><?php echo $cur_image['filename'].".html"; ?>` , and its working perfectly

Comment: Great. Merry xmas